# Flutter: persistent bottom navigation rebuilds sub-page on tab change

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using the [persistent_bottom_nav_bar package](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar) and have implemented it as outlined in their Readme. Please refer to the **main.dart** code below.

**The issue**: On `page1`, I can navigate in to a sub-page that contains a ListView. When on that sub-page, if I don't pop that page but just directly tap on the bottom navigation items to change page, that ListView on the the sub-page continues to rebuild for every tab that I navigate to. Not sure how to prevent that from happening??

In my actual implementation (the below is a simplified code), this sub-page is a stateful widget. I therefore tried to extend the stateful widget with `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` to not rebuild the page, but that didn't help. In the example I've given here, the sub-page is in fact a stateless widget and the issue still happens. So I suspect it stems from the package itself and not whether the page is stateful or stateless.

Anyone who might have any ideas of what's going on? Thanks in advance.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:persistent_bottom_nav_bar/persistent-tab-view.dart';

import 'page1.dart';
import 'page2.dart';
import 'page3.dart';
import 'page4.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      home: HomeScaffold(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScaffold extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _HomeScaffoldState createState() => _HomeScaffoldState();
}

class _HomeScaffoldState extends State<HomeScaffold> {
  PersistentTabController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);
  }

  List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
    return [
      Page1(),
      Page2(),
      Page3(),
      Page4(),
    ];
  }

  List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
    return [
      _buildBottomNavBarItem('Page 1', Icons.home),
      _buildBottomNavBarItem('Page 2', Icons.search),
      _buildBottomNavBarItem('Page 3', Icons.message),
      _buildBottomNavBarItem('Page 4', Icons.settings),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return PersistentTabView(
      context,
      controller: _controller,
      screens: _buildScreens(),
      items: _navBarsItems(),
      confineInSafeArea: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true, 
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true, 
      stateManagement: true, 
      // hideNavigationBar: true, 
      hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true, 
      decoration: NavBarDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        colorBehindNavBar: Colors.white,
      ),
      popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
      popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,
      itemAnimationProperties: ItemAnimationProperties( 
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        curve: Curves.ease,
      ),
      screenTransitionAnimation: ScreenTransitionAnimation( 
        animateTabTransition: true,
        curve: Curves.ease,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      ),
      navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style8, 
    );

  }
}

PersistentBottomNavBarItem _buildBottomNavBarItem(String title, IconData icon) {
  return PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
    icon: Icon(icon),
    title: title,
    activeColorPrimary: Colors.indigo,
    inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
  );
}
```

**page1.dart**

```
import 'page1_sub_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page1State createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Building Page1');
    super.build(context);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Center(child: Text('Page1')),
          SizedBox(height: 40),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
              CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Page1SubPage()),
            ),
            child: Text('Sub-page'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**page1_sub_page.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Page1SubPage extends StatelessWidget {
  // Generate dummy list
  final List dummyList = List.generate(100, (index) {
    return {
      "id": index,
      "title": "This is the tile $index",
    };
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: dummyList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                print('Building tile $index');
                return Card(
                  elevation: 6,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      child: Text(dummyList[index]["id"].toString()),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
                    ),
                    title: Text(dummyList[index]["title"]),
                  ),
                );
              } ,
            )));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is this.

```
 stateManagement: false, // Default is true.
```

and use this

```
PersistentNavBarNavigator.pushNewScreen(
        context,
        screen: OrderScreen(),
        withNavBar: false, // OPTIONAL VALUE. True by default.
        pageTransitionAnimation: PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
      );
```